# Is there a print function in Java that is not blocking the UI?

Tags: java, printing, concurrency, awt

In my Java application, there is a printing function.

```
PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
pj.setJobName(myJobName);
pj.setPrintable(myPrintableObject);
if ( pj.printDialog() == false ) {
  return;
}  
pj.print();
```

While the printing job hasn't finished, I am not able to click something else in the UI, because the printing-Job is blocking.

The same applies to the print function of JTextPane:

```
JTextPane jtp = new JTextPane();
       ...         
jtp.print(null, null, show, null, null, show);
```

Is there any possiblity of printing in Java without blocking the UI or do I have to realize that by myself with multiple threads?

Comment: Wrap the Printing task in a `Runnable` and pass it to a `Thread`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are invoking these methods from the main *event dispatcher thread*. That thread exists to serve your UI - it should not be used for any long term activities. Because when you occupy that thread it can't handle events any more and your ui freezes!

You should wrap them into their own threads instead. Or use something like a SwingWorker.

Comment: Thanks! I used a SwingWorker, which was pretty pretty easy. :)